# Can't start mysql server (Mac OS)

Tags: mysql, macos

My computer crashed and I'm having a lot of trouble starting the mysql server.

If I try to start the server through system preferences, then nothing changes and it just remains "stopped". If I run:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

it throws the error:

```
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/xxx.pid)
```

I've tried a bunch of things that I've found, like changing permissions on that directory, but so far I've had no luck whatsoever.

Comment: You might have better luck asking on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: And posting your complete error log content.